Prefect 2.0.x MinIO Storage Block using in Fastapi environment cannot even save newly created Block or Load existing Block
I facing a problem when trying to use Prefect Storage Block in Fastapi. The error is below when I trying to call load or newly created save Block :
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Below are the code service.py:
from prefect import get_client
from prefect_aws.s3 import S3Bucket
import importlib, traceback
from prefect.deployments.deployments import Deployment

class PrefectProvider:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prefect_client = get_client()

    async def register_flow(self, flow_name: str, schedule):
        try:
            minio_storage = await S3Bucket.load("minio-s3")
            flow_fun = importlib.import_module(f"flows.{flow_name}")
            deployment = await Deployment.build_from_flow(
                flow=getattr(flow_fun, flow_name),
                flow_name=flow_name,
                name=f"{flow_name}-deployment",
                schedules=[schedule],
                infra_overrides={"env": {"PREFECT_LOGGING_LEVEL": "DEBUG"}},
                storage=minio_storage,
                work_queue_name="minio-worker"
            )
            deployment_id = await deployment.apply()
            return deployment_id
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            raise e

main.py :
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from service import PrefectProvider
import uvicorn
from prefect.client.schemas.schedules import CronSchedule
from module import prefect_provider_di

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root(provider: PrefectProvider = Depends(prefect_provider_di)):
    await provider.register_flow("my_test_flow", CronSchedule(cron="* * * * *"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

module.py :
from service import PrefectProvider

def prefect_provider_di():
    return PrefectProvider()

And my flows/my_test_flow.py :
from prefect import flow

@flow
def my_test_flow():
    print("Hello guys")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_test_flow()

But when I trying call load without await it complains coroutine 'Block.load' was never awaited, but I works perfectly when I Run code in debug mode using VSCode.
I am using docker environment for this, the service are :
Prefect Server : prefecthq/prefect:2.20-python3.8
Prefect Worker : prefecthq/prefect:2.20-python3.8 with prefect-aws library added
MinIO : minio/minio:RELEASE.2024-08-17T01-24-54Z
Edit :
I don't understand it fixed now after restarting the PC

This does not appear to be a minimal reproduceable post.   Where is the rest of the FULL stack trace of the exception.   also enough code should be present for someone to try the code themselves.  you need to provide example that shows the problem but has enough code for other folks to try it.

Thank you, I have updated my question to add some code example to reproduce the error
